# How does Slideshare.net site works in iPad Safari?

Tags: javascript, html

I am right now exploring on opening Office documents in Mobile browsers but ensuring users do not have access to the file.

I saw that with out even downloading the pps files in to iPad, Slideshare is able to show presentation.

Example: Check this out:
http://www.slideshare.net/invalidname/advanced-av-foundation-cocoaconf-aug-11

Is there any opensource library to accomplish this?

And one another thing is that when I test in iPad and Android, at times I got a pps presentation filled with slides which are images (only option to save) and at times normal slides where I had the option to copy, paste in to it..

Please some one share light on this ?

Comment: They convert the documents to images, you're not looking at a Keynote or PowerPoint files, but to images generated from them. There are many solutions for this in various languages.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares: But when I checked in iPad, at times it was also opened as a slide with text in it. I was able to copy paste the content from it.

Comment: You probably downloaded the file and opened it up in a native viewer. Slideshare shows images only.

Comment: No Mauricio. I am testing it right now. I believe they have both options..But is there any Javascript library does this  as mentioned in answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340020/any-embeddable-document-viewer

Comment: check out speakerdeck if you are considering slideshare. speakerdeck is nasty nice.

Answer (score 1):

It's just like [scribd.com](http://scribd.com), which converts PDF (or other document format) into HTML5, but it seems with a lower conversion ratio in SlideShare. (More text is embedded into images and less text is extracted as selectable text in SlideShare.)

With some open source libraries, you can convert almost any popular document formats into PDF and then extract texts and images from the PDF. Then you can try to put these texts and images into the web page and make the layout to look like the original layout. With HTML5, you can use the same fonts from the PDF in your web page, so they should look more similar than without HTML5.